# I can't mount a windows 10 shared drive

Tags: mount, cifs

I have a shared directory under windows set to full access for everyone.  When I use mount.cifs it just hangs there, and when I use smbclient I get the following error?  I can connects to share fine using my android phone.

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.74/backups /mnt/backups/ -o guest,soft --verbose

smbclient //MY-WINDOWS/backups -N -U Everyone 
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[MY-WINDOWS] OS=[Windows 10 Pro 15063] Server=[Windows 10 Pro 6.3]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Comment: Can you share an smb.conf file?

Comment: I am not using samba, but a real windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using a real user/pass instead of guest account.

Comment: Have you tried edit /etc/fstab so that you can automount it?